# Procedimiento almacenado con insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, insert

He creado un SP para insertar registros a una tabla (dbo.campañaspro) pero me sale el siguiente error: ***Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition***. A mi parecer estoy considerándo la misma cantidad de parámetros. Agradeceré su ayuda.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GenerarCodCab
@acodcab varchar(4),
@acadena varchar(1),
@acampaña varchar(40),
@material varchar(2000),
@fechaini date,
@fechafin date,
@caja varchar(6),
@kiosco varchar(6),
@emision varchar(6),
@acanal varchar(1)
as
    insert into temporal.dbo.campañaspro
    values (@acodcab,@acadena,@acampaña,@material,@fechaini,@fechafin,@caja,@kiosco,@emision,@acanal)

exec sp_GenerarCodCab '912','1','40% EN VINOS SIBARIS UNDURRAGA WONG','000000000000323257;000000000000323258;
    000000000480574001','2019-09-06','2019-10-06','154200','154198','1'
go
```

Comment: El mensajes un poco explicito al indicarte que no estas enviando el mismo esquema de definicion de la tabla. O sea me parece que te faltan columnas
¿Podrias colocar el esquema de la tabla  temporal.dbo.campañaspro asi lo podemos probar?

Comment: Nunca escribas un `insert` sin especificar las columnas, sino justamente vas a tener estos problemas. Revisa la respuesta de roloram que por ahí va la cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar incluir la lista de columnas de la tabla en el insert:

```
insert into temporal.dbo.campañaspro (acodcab, acadena, ....)
    values (@acodcab,@acadena,@acampaña,@material,@fechaini,@fechafin,@caja,@kiosco,@emision,@acanal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no estas enviando la misma cantidad de parámetros al llamar al procedimiento almacenado (SP). Es decir tu Procedimiento tiene 10 parámetros pero tu lo estas llamando con 9

Mira si tenemos este SP con 10 parametros

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GenerarCodCab
@acodcab varchar(4),
@acadena varchar(1),
@acampaña varchar(40),
@material varchar(2000),
@fechaini date,
@fechafin date,
@caja varchar(6),
@kiosco varchar(6),
@emision varchar(6),
@acanal varchar(1)
AS

PRINT 'Demo'


--insert into temporal.dbo.campañaspro
--values (@acodcab,@acadena,@acampaña,@material,@fechaini,@fechafin,@caja,@kiosco,@emision,@acanal)

GO
```

Tu lo llamas con 9

```
exec sp_GenerarCodCab '912','1','40% EN VINOS SIBARIS UNDURRAGA WONG','000000000000323257;000000000000323258;
000000000480574001','2019-09-06','2019-10-06','154200','154198','1'
```

Y lo quieres probar puede pasarle por nombre los parámetros. algo asi... (aqui estan los 10) por eso en @emision coloco '?????' 
Este sentencia si llama correctamente el SP sp_GenerarCodCab

```
EXEC sp_GenerarCodCab
@acodcab = '912',
@acadena = '1',
@acampaña = '40% EN VINOS SIBARIS UNDURRAGA WONG',
@material = '000000000000323257;000000000000323258; 000000000480574001',
@fechaini = '2019-09-06',
@fechafin = '2019-10-06',
@caja = '154200',
@kiosco = '154198',
@emision = '??????',
@acanal = '1'
```

Y tu lo estas enviando
Como veras falta un parámetro. Dale una mirada. Repasalo. 
Por ejemplo en el que envías falta algo entre @emision y @acanal

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: El error es del `insert` no del `execute`.

Comment: Si. Por eso digo que es un error de la cantidad de parámetros que esta pasando al llamar al Procedimiento Almacenado

Comment: No, no tiene que ver con los parámetros enviados. Tiene que ver con como está escrito el insert dentro del procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: @LuisCazares si bien puede ser un problema. Deberia tener un GO por lo menos en su script de ejemplo. Eso no acarra ningun mensaje de error. Puedes incluso llamar al mismo SP en un ALTER y no da error... [mira el ejemplo](https://i.imgur.com/WGwcvAN.png). Pero  [si lo llamas el SP con el ejemplo que envio  da un mensaje de error](https://i.imgur.com/8HOOkEX.png). Pero ademas tamben debe tener el mismo error al momento de insert (por eso le pedi el esquema de la tabla y probamos directamente completo el circuito)